# Can't append matrix to array in python

Tags: python, matrix, append

I've been writing some code in Python that should return an array of matrices from one starting matrix. Basically, you give the function a matrix and there are some if conditions that change certain numbers in it, then I add that matrix to the list of all matrices but it turns out that every time I add a new matrix I add the same exact one.

Here is my code:

```
arr = []
arr.append(staring_mat)

test = arr[:] # copying arr

matrix = staring_mat

for k in range(10):
  temporary = matrix
  for i in range(20):
    for j in range(20):
      number = do_something(i,j,temporary)
      if number < 15:
        temporary[i][j] = 12
      if number > 60:
        temporary[i][j] = 54
        .
        .
        .
  test.append(temporary)
  
  for num in range(len(test)):
    print(test[num])
    print('\n')
  
  matrix = temporary
  
 arr.extend(test)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
matrix = staring_mat
temporary = matrix
```

By doing this you're creating a shallow copy, changes to the copy also affects the original. You should create a deep copy, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)'s the docs.

```
test = arr[:]
```

Here you're creating a deep copy.